# Getting high resolution event picture using Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get a high-res picture from public events on Facebook using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/picture/) document. I have:

```
Facebook.api(event.id + "/picture?redirect=false&type=large" , []).then(response => {
if (response && !response.error) {
    alert('response: ' + JSON.stringify(response) );
    event.imageURL= response.data.url;
}
else {
    alert( 'Error=  ' + response.error);
}
});
```

But even with `type=large`, the picture that I get is very low resolution. I have also tried to set the height or width: `height=500`, but the API returns silhouette.

I have seen other apps can import higher resolution of event pictures. What am I missing?

Ideally I would like to get pictures of several events in one API call. I'm able to do this using this search string:

```
/picture?redirect=0&type=large&ids=...
```

But the pictures that I get are still not high resolution.

Comment: type=large gives me a 200*200px image, whereas without it it is only 50*50 ... so presumably that’s the largest you can get. But maybe you want the `cover` instead …?

Comment: Thanks I will try cover